# Javascript sorting a date (mm/dd/yyyy) not working in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I sort below array of dates in ascending as well as descending order? For example, I have:

```js
var value = [
        {"ID":"3","date":null},
        {"ID":"24","date":"07/28/2017"},
        {"ID":"65","date":"05/14/2018"},
        {"ID":"36","date":"06/11/2017"},
        {"ID":"27","date":null},
        {"ID":"18","date":"02/26/2018"},
        {"ID":"37","date":null},
        {"ID":"39","date":"05/15/2017"},
        {"ID":"10","date":"06/11/2017"},
        {"ID":"4","date":null},
        {"ID":"8","date":null},
        {"ID":"12","date":"05/15/2017"},
        {"ID":"14","date":"07/28/2017"},
        {"ID":"19","date":"06/11/2017"}
        ];
```

I'd like the resultant array to look like:

```js
var result = [
        {"ID":"3","date":null},
        {"ID":"27","date":null},
        {"ID":"4","date":null},
        {"ID":"8","date":null},
        {"ID":"39","date":"05/15/2017"},
        {"ID":"12","date":"05/15/2017"},
        {"ID":"36","date":"06/11/2017"},
        {"ID":"10","date":"06/11/2017"},
        {"ID":"19","date":"06/11/2017"}
        {"ID":"24","date":"07/28/2017"},
        {"ID":"14","date":"07/28/2017"},
        {"ID":"18","date":"02/26/2018"},
        {"ID":"65","date":"05/14/2018"}
        ];
```

```
Javascript sorting function :
```

```js
function sortArray(desc, value) {
  if (desc) {
    value.sort(function(a: any, b: any) {
      let aValue = (a["date"]) ? Number(new Date(a["date"])) : Number(new Date(0));
      let bValue = (b["date"]) ? Number(new Date(b["date"])) : Number(new Date(0));
      return bValue - aValue;
    });
  } else {
    value.sort(function(a: any, b: any) {
      let aValue = (a["date"]) ? Number(new Date(a["date"])) : Number(new Date(0));
      let bValue = (b["date"]) ? Number(new Date(b["date"])) : Number(new Date(0));
      return aValue - bValue;
    });
  }
}
```

I have mention input array as well as expected array.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: Hi @RomanKoliada. My question is different. you can see array which contain null value too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ES6 syntax, and play with `.reverse()` to get **ASC** or **DESC**

```
value.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)).reverse()
```

Demo - https://jsfiddle.net/zkcsdv01/

or look here for more extended answer [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: @SwapnilYeole It is

Comment: Thanks - this is excellent because the normal ES6 fat arrow function does not work on dates without the `... new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date) ...` I was trying to do it with just `... b.date - a.date ...`